# Laptop freezing constantly; sometimes no operation system found

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, freeze

It's a few years old Acer. It was used with Win7 for many years, and the user always complained how "everything freezes", or how it says "Operation system not found" when trying to power-up, etc etc. I ran a HDTune, saw red sectors immediately, formatted everything, installed LXLE (Lubuntu).

From then been using the laptop myself infrequently, also ran some tests, don't really recall which ones, some defaults probably found on Linux Live CDs when trying out which system to install. No red sectors on HDD, RAM also seemed fine, no problems found.

However as a few months passed "Operating system not found" kept coming more frequently, maybe once in 5 power-ons. Usually one restart is good enough for system to launch up correctly, however now I started noticing those freezes when using the laptop regularly, as well as "Operation system not found" coming up 50% of the time I would say.

Regarding 'freezes' - I monitor the system, when the freezes (or major slower-downs) happen the CPU usage and temperature do not increase, no hikes in RAM usage as well. If a music is playing in background it does not stop, everything is ok, it's just I cannot press anything, because nothing is responding.

It does tell me that there's definitely something wrong with either RAM or HDD, I'm just not sure which tests exactly to run, and what should I be looking there, since previous ones did not show anything wrong with the machine. Can someone recommend something specifically?

Comment: Possible failing disk. Check your HDD for SMART errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boot issue is most likely indicative of either a failing disk, or it's an issue with one of the many subsystems required to do so (such as the SouthBridge). The freeze also makes me think one of the above is the issue, as I've seen similar behaviour when the system suddenly has its I/O operations hang.

Before doing anything else, back up what you can/want from the disk. If it is the source of the problem, there's no telling when it'll fail for good. As for the actual tests, I can think of two off the top of my head:

**smartctl** 
- This will show you a lot of info about the disk that is usually hidden from the user. One feature of the SMART system is that a disk keeps track of important statistics such as read/write fails, so that these can be used for telling when a disk is about to fail.

**fsck**
- While your problem looks like it's purely hardware related, I suggest you do a filesystem scan anyway. It might come over something, or at the very least it'll be a small stress-test.

Comment: I did Smartctl, it says just as previously 'completed without error'. There are 1508 ATA errors, but everywhere I read googling it says to not worry about those. So not exactly sure what to make out of it.